# Moving the text within a text input

Tags: css, input

I've made a form, but where I've added a 0px margin to it, it has also applied that margin to text inside the input (e.g. where you would put your name, for a username input) meaning that it's against the left hand edge of the box.

How can I added a margin to the text within the box, while keeping the margin on the box itself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for padding not margin.

Margin is outside of the element and padding is on the inside

Comment: Great, should've of thought of that really. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293807/302229 is more usefull, in case you are using visible borders

Answer (score 13):

I dont think the people here understand your question completely. The OP is asking how he can apply a margin to the text inside the input form while also still having a margin on the input itself.

His question is stated a little wrong. What he's looking for is how to INDENT the text inside the input. Use:

```
text-indent: 10px; // or whatever size you need
```

EDIT: I do realize this is a 7 year old response, but there really aren't any other proper answers to this via google search.

Answer (score 4):

Set padding to the text box. Like:

`input.text{padding:5px;}` This means `padding-top:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:5px;`

Also, I'm assuming the class name of your text input is `text`

Answer (score 0):

You can position text inside input field of type text using the text-indent property as follow:

```
text-indent : value;
```

In value you specify the value by which you want your text to be positioned that much to left.